# How to submit code (visual studio projects, C#, OpenCL) with my IEEE paper submission

Tags: paper-submission, ieee, code

I am trying to submit a paper to IEEE ([transactions on signal processing](https://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/tsp-ieee)). Along with my paper I have written some code (Visual studio projects, C#, OpenCL and accompanying dlls and exes).

The software is about 25MB in size (once compressed to zip). While I can submit the code text files with my submission very easily, the full working solution is not easy to submit with my paper. The IEEE submission system does not appear to like zip files. I would like to submit my code to the journal in a form that is easy for them to run so easily see how I produced my results.

What options do I have for doing this?

In future I would like to put the code on github as well but I am not sure what stage in the process is best for this.

Comment: I was also wondering if I could use research gate or something similar for this purpose

Comment: Why do not just put the code on GitHub and put a link inside your paper?

Comment: I actually intend to put the code up on GitHub after publishing, but I was concerned that the Journal might not like me doing this before publishing. Are my worries about this unfounded?

Comment: I guess, only if the journal's staff inadequate; rough, but true. How a proper link to a related external published source (my, or my colleagues) could be a problem? You may want to ask them, just for sure or read their terms. Nevertheless, such policies will be appeared as strange terms. Author should give them an unique decent article, not an exclusive access and rights to all related staff.

Comment: I'd suggest to publish it on [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/about). That is persistent storage, unlike the GitHub repository, and there is a convenient way to archive a release made from the GitHub repository on Zenodo: https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/. In which form does the software exist now, and under which license it is available?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov The software is just a zip file with all my code and data sets. I was thinking maybe BSD 3 clause .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [code ocean](https://codeocean.com/)

I can run my program in a docker container so others can see my results and reproduce them. It also allows me to choose between sharing publicly and with specific people.